# Factorial algorithm more efficient than naive multiplication

Tags: algorithms, efficiency, arithmetic

I know how to code for factorials using both iterative and recursive (e.g. `n * factorial(n-1)` for e.g.). I read in a textbook (without been given any further explanations) that there is an even more efficient way of coding for factorials by dividing them in half recursively.

I understand why that may be the case. However I wanted to try coding it on my own, and I don't think I know where to start though. A friend suggested I write base cases first. and I was thinking of using arrays so that I can keep track of the numbers... but I really can't see any way out to designing such a code.

What kind of techniques should I be researching?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/143090/755

Comment: Here's a method that cuts the number of multiplications needed to get $n!$ by half. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42510/what-are-the-benefits-of-cutting-by-half-the-number-of-multiplications-needed-to

Comment: Here's a method that can get a factorial without using a single multiplication during the process. the method uses pre-computed squares and stored for future use by those who deals with factorials on a daily basis.  
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711223/does-using-pre-computed-squares-speed-up-significantly-the-calculation-of-factor

Comment: Here's a method that doesn't use a single multiplication.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711223/does-using-pre-computed-squares-speed-up-significantly-the-calculation-of-factor

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The best algorithm that is known is to express the factorial as a product of prime powers.  One can quickly determine the primes as well as the right power for each prime using a sieve approach.  Computing each power can be done efficiently using repeated squaring, and then the factors are multiplied together.  This was described by Peter B. Borwein, *On the Complexity of Calculating Factorials*, Journal of Algorithms **6** 376–380, 1985. ([PDF](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P29.pdf))  In short, $n!$ can be computed in $O(n(\log n)^3\log \log n)$ time, compared to the $\Omega(n^2 \log n)$ time required when using the definition.

What the textbook perhaps meant was the divide-and-conquer method.  One can reduce the $n-1$ multiplications by using the regular pattern of the product.

Let $n?$ denote $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \dotsm (2n-1)$ as a convenient notation.
Rearrange the factors of $(2n)! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \dotsm (2n)$ as
$$(2n)! = n! \cdot 2^n \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \dotsm (2n-1).$$
Now suppose $n = 2^k$ for some integer $k>0$.
(This is a useful assumption to avoid complications in the following discussion, and the idea can be extended to general $n$.)
Then $(2^k)! = (2^{k-1})!2^{2^{k-1}}(2^{k-1})?$ and by expanding this recurrence,
$$(2^k)! =  \left(2^{2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}+\dots+2^0}\right) \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (2^i)? = \left(2^{2^k - 1}\right) \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (2^i)?.$$
Computing $(2^{k-1})?$ and multiplying the partial products at each stage takes $(k-2) + 2^{k-1} - 2$ multiplications.  This is an improvement of a factor of nearly $2$ from $2^k-2$ multiplications just using the definition.  Some additional operations are required to compute the power of $2$, but in binary arithmetic this can be done cheaply (depending on what precisely is required, it may just require adding a suffix of $2^k-1$ zeroes).

The following Ruby code implements a simplified version of this.  This does not avoid recomputing $n?$ even where it could do so:

```
def oddprod(l,h)
  p = 1
  ml = (l%2>0) ? l : (l+1)
  mh = (h%2>0) ? h : (h-1)
  while ml <= mh do
    p = p * ml
    ml = ml + 2
  end
  p
end

def fact(k)
  f = 1
  for i in 1..k-1
    f *= oddprod(3, 2 ** (i + 1) - 1)
  end
  2 ** (2 ** k - 1) * f
end

print fact(15)
```

Even this first-pass code improves on the trivial

```
f = 1; (1..32768).map{ |i| f *= i }; print f
```

by about 20% in my testing.

With a bit of work, this can be improved further, also removing the requirement that $n$ be a power of $2$ (see the [extensive discussion](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/description.html)).

Comment: You left out an important factor. The calculation time according to Borwein's paper is not O (n log n log log n). It is O (M (n log n) log log n), where M (n log n) is the time for multiplying two numbers of size n log n.

Comment: Here's a method that cuts the number of multiplications needed to get n!
 by half. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42510/what-are-the-benefits-of-cutting-by-half-the-number-of-multiplications-needed-to

Comment: Here's a method that uses no multiplication.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711223/does-using-pre-computed-squares-speed-up-significantly-the-calculation-of-factor

Answer (score 22):

Keep in mind that the factorial function grows so fast that you'll need [arbitrary-sized integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) to get any benefit of more efficient techniques than the naive approach. The factorial of 21 is already too big to fit in a 64-bit `unsigned long long int`.

As far as I know, there is no algorithm to compute $n!$ (factorial of $n$) which is faster than doing the multiplications.¹

However, the order in which you do the multiplications matter. Multiplication on a machine integer is a basic operation that takes the same time no matter what the value of the integer is. But for arbitrary-sized integers, the time it takes to multiply *a* and *b* depends on the size of *a* and *b*: a naive algorithm operates in time $\Theta(|a| \cdot |b|)$ (where $|x|$ is the number of digits of $x$ — in whatever base you like, as the result is the same up to a multiplicative constant). There are [faster multiplication algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm), but there is an obvious lower bound of $\Omega(|a| + |b|)$ since multiplication has to at least read all the digits. All known multiplication algorithms grow faster than linearly in $\max(|a|,|b|)$.

Armed with this background, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Computation) should make sense.

Since the complexity of multiplications depend on the size of the integers that are being multiplied, you can save time by arranging multiplications in an order that keeps the numbers being multiplied small. It works out better if you arrange for the numbers to be of roughly the same size. The “division in half” that your textbook refers to consists of the following [divide-and-conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) approach to multiply a (multi)set of integers:

1. Arrange the numbers to be multiplied (initially, all the integers from $1$ to $n$) in two sets whose product is roughly the same size. This is a lot less expensive than doing the multiplication: $|a \cdot b| \approx |a| + |b|$ (one machine addition).
2. Apply the algorithm recursively on each of the two subsets.
3. Multiply the two intermediate results.

See the [GMP manual](http://gmplib.org/manual/Factorial-Algorithm.html) for more specifics.

There are even faster methods that not only rearrange the factors $1$ to $n$ but split the numbers by decomposing them into their prime factorization and rearranging the resulting very long product of mostly-small integers. I'll just cite the references from the Wikipedia article: [“On the Complexity of Calculating Factorials” by Peter Borwein](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P29.pdf) and [implementations by Peter Luschny](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm).

¹  <sub>There are faster ways of computing *approximations* of $n!$, but that's not computing the factorial any more, it's computing an approximation of it.</sub>

Comment: Here's a method that cuts the number of multiplications needed to get n! by half.
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42510/what-are-the-benefits-of-cutting-by-half-the-number-of-multiplications-needed-to

Comment: Here's a method that doesn't use multiplications to calculate the factorials. //
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711223/does-using-pre-computed-squares-speed-up-significantly-the-calculation-of-factor

Answer (score 11):

Since the factorial function grows so fast, your computer can only store $n!$ for relatively small $n$. For example, a *double* can store values up to $171!$. So if you want a really fast algorithm for computing $n!$, just use a table of size $171$.

The question becomes more interesting if you're interested in $\log(n!)$ or in the $\Gamma$ function (or in $\log \Gamma$). In all these cases (including $n!$), I don't really understand the comment in your textbook.

As an aside, your iterative and recursive algorithms are equivalent (up to floating point errors), since you are using tail recursion.

Comment: "your iterative and recursive algorithms are equivalent" you're referring to the their asymptotic complexity, right? 
as for the comment in the textbook, well i'm translating it from another language so, maybe my translation sucks.

Comment: The book talks about iterative and recursive, and then comments on how if you use divide and conquer to divide n! in half you can get a way faster solution...

Comment: My notion of equivalence isn't completely formal, but you could say that the arithmetic operations performed are the same (if you switch the order of the operands in the recursive algorithm). An "inherently" different algorithm will perform a different calculation, perhaps using some "trick".

Comment: If you consider the size of the integer as a parameter in the complexity of multiplication, the overall complexity can change even if the arithmetic operations are "the same".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Please how did you arrive at this? --> "For example, a double can store values up to 171!. So if you want a really fast algorithm for computing n!, just use a table of size 171" Are you suggesting a pre-computed table?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu Right, you could use a table.

Comment: Here's a method that doesn't use multiplications to calculate factorials.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711223/does-using-pre-computed-squares-speed-up-significantly-the-calculation-of-factor

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is about finding the exact integer $n!$, not any floating-point approximation, for example. Very roughly $n! ≈ (n/e)^n$, so $\log n! ≈ n (\log n - \log e)$. In practice we can assume that $n << 2^{64}$, otherwise we would need at least $2^{64} \cdot (64 - \log e)$ bits, which is about $2^{67}$ bytes or about 130 million terabytes.

We can multiply a k-bit number by a 64 bit number in O (k). The naive multiplication multiplies n k-bit numbers from 0 to $k(\log k - \log e)$ with a 64 bit numbers, so it takes about $n^2 \log n$ operations. If we can't multiply to m-bit numbers faster than in $O(m^2)$ then this beats any clever divide-and-conquer technique, which will at least multiply two $(n/2) (\log n - 1 - \log e)$ numbers as the last step, taking $O(n^2 \log^2 n)$ operations.

But if we can multiply two m-bit numbers in M(m) operations where M(m) is much smaller than $m^2$, then we can split the n numbers that we need to multiply into 2 groups with similar sized product, for example taking the 1st and 4th, 5th and 8th, 9th and 12th number vs the 2nd and 3rd, 6th an 7th, 10th and 11th number, and do this recursively. The Karatsuba algorithm works in $O(m^{1.58})$ and is quite accessible, but there are faster methods not much above O(m \log m). Using the Karatsuba algorithm, you should be able to calculate $(2^{32})!$ on a not very expensive computer in reasonable time. You'll need about 16 GB for the result alone.

Comment: Here's a method that cuts the number of multiplications needed to get n!
 by half. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42510/what-are-the-benefits-of-cutting-by-half-the-number-of-multiplications-needed-to

Answer (score 0):

Is the text book written Fundamentals of Algorithms, or Art of Programming  by Knuth?

The following method is very effective:

1. Compute binomial coefficient (n, r), using the formula, by repeated  multiplication,

(1+b)^n = 1 + (n,1)b + (n, 2)b^2 + ..... + (n, r)b^r + ....
If you choose b large enough, for example, b = 2^n, there is no carry generated between the coefficients, so, you can select (n, r)

2. Suppose you want to compute m!.

Select N, much larger than m, for example, say N = m^m, and compute

K = integer(N^m/(N, m)),.  Then K = m!

Here both exponent is computed by repeated multiplication.

Example : 8! = 40320 = integer( N^8/(N, 8)) for any N ≥ 1128977